# Div with background image and no content not displaying with percentage declaration

Tags: background-image, percentage

i want to display a div with a background image. I don´t want the div to have any other content than the background image and i don´t want to use a img instead.

It would work with fixed values like height: 100px, but i want to use percentage declaration.
Why is it not showing? Is it even possible with percentage values? Or do i have to declare anything else?

I want to build a RESPONSIVE mobile site, where i can use template buttons and fill it with html text so i don´t need to use several images for the same button with different text. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance here is my code:

```
<div id="icon1">

</div>

 #icon1 {
   background-image: url(images/MyPicture.png);
   width: 30% ;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using one of the numerous tried and tested responsive frameworks?

Comment: I tried jQuery Mobile but it didn´t change anything.. Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

it'd only work if a percentage height is set to all of the parent elements of the DIV#icon1  up to the BODY and HTML tags.

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/YJQcF/1/
```

Otherwise, it'll need fixed height or min-height values to be assigned to it;